# How do you apply conditional css on a child component's input field in Angular 5?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I am running into issues trying to style a child component's autocomplete field's background color dynamically based off a boolean condition.

In my parent component, I have a search component that contains a Angular Material autocomplete field:

```
<search (notify)="onSearch($event, i)" searchType="Product" 
    [(value)]="repair.product" 
    [ngClass]="{'error-color': repair.invalidProduct}"></search>
```

And in my parent component's scss I have this class:

```
:host ::ng-deep search.input .error-color {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.48);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what's `<search></search>` is that your component ?

Comment: Correct that is my custom component

Comment: so why not use property binding  and pass in a Boolean, which will be used INSIDE the component ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
search.error-color ::ng-deep  input {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.48);
}
```

Or no encapsulation styles in component

```
@Component({
// ...
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
styles: [
  // ...
]
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this ended up being the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you can pass a boolean, from the parent component to the child component using property binding - @input() and use that inside the child component.

so in your parent:

```
<search [isInvalid]="repair.invalidProduct"></search>
```

and inside the child component (search):

search.component.TS:

```
@Input() isInvalid = false;
```

search.component.HTML:

```
<input [ngClass]="{'error-color': isInvalid}" />
```

search.component.CSS:

```
.error-color { background-color: red }
```